# How to solve save/persist entity in concurrent transaction and What is the best approach to handle concurrent requests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to solve save/persist entity in concurrent transaction and What is the best approach to handle concurrent requests?

The problem, being encountered is due to concurrency of both the book creation requests, both the instances check that book does not exist in the beginning, both try to create the book in the database, one succeeds other fails.

Let say we have one table with three columns

Table = BOOK
COLUMNS = ID, NAME, AUTHOR

Table also has unique constraint on name and author column.

CONSTRAINT uq_book UNIQUE (NAME, AUTHOR)

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class BookRepository implements IBookRepository
{
    
    @Autowired
    ISpringJpaBookRepository springJpaBookRepository;

    @Override
    public Book createBook(Book book) throws Exception {

        BookEntity bookEntity = springJpaBookRepository.getByNameAndAuthor(book.getName(), book.getAuthor())
        //Create a book entity and save
        BookEntity bookEntity = createBook(getBookEntity(book));
        
        bookEntity = springJpaBookRepository.save(bookEntity);
        
        Book bookCreated = getBookFromEntity(bookEntity);
        
        return bookCreated;
    }
}


public class BookService implements IBookService
{
    @Autowired
    IBookRepository bookRepository;
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Book createBook(Book book) throws Exception {
        bookRepository .createBook(Book book);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? I don't see a question. What's the issue with one transaction failing? It's not like you could do anything else.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov Yes you are correct, Need to modify question here.                        let say we have column LOCATION instead on AUTHOR  and we keep entries like 'india/delhi/rohini' in location column, and we don't want to add 'india/delhi' if 'india/delhi/rohini' is already there in database. But in concurrent requests it will create 2 entries in database.

Comment: How to avoid that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but how about splitting the column into 2 parts and make the part that contains country/city unique?